# Syntax of variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

Are two following syntax equal?

```
#1
var option_1 = 0;
var option_2 = 0;

#2
var option_1 = 0, option_2;
```

I've recently came across to the syntax shown in #2 while didn't get it completely. Is it a short way of variable declaration of #1?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: #2 does not equal #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not the same. This would be the same:

```
var option_1 = 0, option_2 = 0;
```

In your case #2 has `option_1` set to `0`, and `option_2` being `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes except you forgot to assign `0` to `option_2`.

```
var option_1 = 0, option_2 = 0;
```

You'll also commonly see this with line breaks.

```
var option_1 = 0,
    option_2 = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the code with

```
var option_1 = 0, option_2 = 0;
```

But

```
var option_1 = 0, option_2;
```

Will set `option_1` to `0` and `option_2` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Your second one doesn't declare `option_2` and will create a global variable in non-strict mode.

Comment: good point, probably a bad example, let me remove that